# Find Flatten Heightmap in Unity3d 4.2

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity3D Editor. I can not find Terrian Flatten Heightmap . Is there anyone know how to add a value to Flatten Heightmap in Unity3D 4.2?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I have no idea what it is you're looking for or what you're trying to achieve. Could you clarify?

Comment: It's pretty clear, "Flatten Heightmap" was an option in the "Terrain" menu but that menu does not longer exists... so where is this option now?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After selecting your terrain go to the **Inspector** panel and then click the Paint Height button [image: icon] and then change the **Height** property value and click 
[image: the flatten button]

Comment: Thank you a lot @Ivan Castellanos